# Does the range of Message refer to straight-line distance or distance along a clear path?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The Message cantrip has a range of 120 feet. However, it also includes this clause:

> You can cast this spell through solid objects if you are familiar with the target and know it is beyond the barrier. Magical silence, 1 foot of stone, 1 inch of common metal, a thin sheet of lead, or 3 feet of wood blocks the spell. The spell doesn't have to follow a straight line and can travel freely around corners or through openings.

Suppose I am 100 feet away from my target, and there is a gigantic solid block of lead between us, completely blocking any direct path. However, the wall has a hollow, twisty, winding tube connecting one side to the other, with a total length much longer than 120 feet. Does this allow me to communicate with my target via Message, since there is a clear path (through the tube) and the target is within range? Or does the range need to be measured along the path that the message spell is taking, in which case the spell would fail?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, who has ever actually encountered such an artificially contrived condition in actual play?

Second, if the target is within range and there is an unblocked path *of any length* the spell works. The range of a spell is a sphere around the caster. Normally a spell requires a clear line of effect in a straight line between the caster and the target but the specifics *Message* override this by stating "The spell doesn't have to follow a straight line and can travel freely around corners or through openings." It doesn't put any limitation on how long this path can be.

Comment: I could imagine such a contrived condition in an adversarial module like Tomb of Horrors.

Comment: Well, the example was purposely contrived to highlight the mechanical question being asked. For a more realistic example, one could imagine a thick wall of stone 60 feet high, with me and the target standing on opposite sides, such that the unobstructed up and over the wall is over 120 feet long, despite the target being only 10 or 20 feet away.

Comment: I'm definitely going to cast message through the line of my huge ant farm now. Thanks for the idea.